# Select text inside html table cell upon tabbing into the cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, tablecell

I feel silly for asking this, it seems like it should be very simple, and yet after several hours - here I am.

I have an HTML Table with `<td>` cells inside. Each cell has a default of "0". I'm trying to figure out how to select the cell contents upon tabbing and/or clicking into the cell. I've tried using CSS (i.e,. user-select: all; user-select: text) and the best I can do with javascript is to clear the cell on click:

```
document.getElementById(tableId).addEventListener('click', (e) => {
     if (!e.target.contentEditable === "true") return; //using this to register clicks on a cell
     e.target.innerText = ""
 })
```

I'd really like to just select the contents - not clear them - so the user can leave the value there and tab to the next one if they want to keep the default value. I've tried using "focus" events and the like, to no avail. How do I just select the text inside?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You need to create a range, and set it as the window's selected text (https://www.sanwebe.com/2014/04/select-all-text-in-element-on-click#:~:text=To%20select%20all%20text%20inside%20an%20element%20such,%28%29%20to%20select%20the%20range%20of%20the%20element.)

Comment: Thanks - the link was helpful. I was hopeful there would be a more simple solution. I have it working with an on-click event - but how do I get this to trigger when I tab into a cell?

Comment: tried onfocus and addEventListener ("focus", fn) to no avail. I think this is because I'm adding the event listener to the table, not each individual cell, so the table focus isn't changing as I tab through cells...is there a way around this, or should I just select all <td> children and add the focus event to each using a loop/forEach?

Comment: That was my problem - I had the focus on the table (which worked for clicks). Used a loop to add the event to each cell and it works now. Thanks! If you add your comment as an answer, I'm happy to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Try using onfocus" (on the cells in the table)

Comment: Who are you quoting there?

Comment: @isherwood myself - my comment. I am following up on OP's comment that I could/should submit this as an answer so s/he could mark it as correct

Comment: 1) Comments are to be considered temporary. Don't use them as references (let alone in such a vague manner). 2) Comment-answers should be removed, _especially_ after you've made them redundant with a proper answer. I've flagged yours for deletion.  3) Quoting yourself is just weird. :P

Comment: I submitted an edit to the answer to fill it out with all relevant information from the comments.